# How to make JavaScript function visible in Eclipse "Outline View"?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdt

I have such code but can not turn on outline of function if it defined in anonymous function - there is not problem with class.

How can I outline `something2` - please share some hints?

I can mark all function as constructors but it is invalid approach.

[image: screenshot of bad outline]

```
// --- start of track event ---
// required debug.js
(function (window) {

/**
 * @memberof erest.track_event
 */ 
function something2() {
}

/**
 * @memberof erest.track_event
 * @constructor
 */
function something3() {
}
}(window));
//--- end of track event ---

function something1() {
}
```

I was tested all filtering options, jsdoc and study Eclipse preferences but has no idea what to do to make `something2` visible in outline view?

[image: second attempt]

Comment: I am running Eclipse Luna (latest available) and am still suffering this puzzle.

Comment: Note that only the first level is shown in the outline ([by design](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472855)), so it won't work if you have your JS code wrapped in a self-executing anonymous function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a small typo in the `@memberOf` annotation. Change to a capital O and it should work just fine:

```
(function(window) {

  /**
   * @memberOf erest.track_event
   */
   function something2() {
   }

  /**
   * @memberOf erest.track_event
   * @constructor
   */
   function something3() {
   }

}(window));

function something1() {
}
```

[image: Outline Screenshot]

Remove the `@constructor` annotation, if appropriate, to get something3() in the outline and not the constructor function.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600168/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-that-creates-an-outline-view-for-the-javascript-reve/12837009#12837009) is a similar question asked. Follow the link in the answer to get some more information.

Comment: From my perspective, your recipe seems to work.  I find it interesting that the tag needs to be `@memberOf` as opposed to `@memberof` (see ... http://usejsdoc.org/tags-memberof.html)

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I found the issue of this question while reading [this post](http://www.kajabity.com/2012/02/how-i-introduced-jsdoc-into-a-javascript-project-and-found-my-eclipse-outline/). It seems to be an odd behavior of the outline view. But I don't have any details about the implementation.