# How to write private and public functions inside a javascript class in order to have them highlighted differently in eclipse outline view

Tags: javascript, eclipse, syntax

I'm writing a JavaScript class that looks like bellow and using Eclipse IDE for the task. (Eclipse Neon to be specific)

```
function Test(){}
(function()
{

    var abc = 1;

    // private function
    function foo(){
        // do stuff
        console.log('private FUNC');
    }

    // public function
    this.publicStuff = function(){
        // do something
        abc++;
        foo();
    }

}).apply(Test)
```

While the class grows bigger I'm using Eclipse's outline view to navigate inside it, BUT this is how eclipse is showing me the outline for the above

[image: eclipse neon JavaScript test class print screen with outline]

As you can see the private function **foo** is shown using the green icon which means public. The private variable is **abc** is shown green (public) also and the public function is not shown

Truth is that I'm a beginner in writing real deal JavaScript even if I'm writing small JavaScript functions to help the UI here and there for a while now.

Can anyone guide me in how to write a JavaScript class and have it nicely highlighted in eclipse outline view. (not changing eclipse though)

Thanks

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544328/how-to-make-javascript-function-visible-in-eclipse-outline-view

Comment: by the way, the @memberOf  annotation produces no effect. I'm running eclipse for PHP developers, am I missing some plugin or something?